# FB.Data.* JS sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have used FB.Data.* methods a lot in my facebook application, but according to the "Developer Roadamp", it will be deprecated after January 1, 2012. Does it mean that the FB.Data.* methods in my app will not work after January 1, 2012, and I need to look for some other solutions to replace the FB.Data.* methods?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes.

Unless they're keeping the methods around for legacy code(temporarily). Either way, you'll have to find new functions eventually.

Comment: They've been considered deprecated since August 2010 I believe; though for some reason the actual removal isn't scheduled until sometime after Jan 1 2012

Comment: Deprecated code is usually kept around for awhile, so that developers have time to update their code to new functions, and then taken out of the codebase at a later date. That's why the actual removal is scheduled for Jan, but they were deprecated in Aug.